# Ошибка с подключением Spring к MongoDB

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot, mongodb

Существует следующий интерфейс:

```
interface GameDaoMongoRepository : MongoRepository<Game, Int>
```

И модель:

```
@Document(collection = "game")
class Game(
    var board: Board,
    private val timeToMove: Int,
    private val giveaway: Boolean,
    private val fullAttack: Boolean,
    @Id var id: Int = 0
)
```

Стектрейс при запуске приложения:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.TaskQueue java.util.Timer.queue accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @6a28ffa4
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at me.oqaris.checkers.CheckersApplicationKt.main(CheckersApplication.kt:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.TaskQueue java.util.Timer.queue accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @6a28ffa4
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:791) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:424) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:602) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:556) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:424) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:602) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:556) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:424) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:341) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:494) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:486) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Файл конфигурации:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=checkers
```

Замечу, что в MongoDB Compass подключение создаётся успешно.

Все зависимости `spring-boot`, в том числе `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` подключены.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в 17 версии Java. При переходе на 11 версию осталось только предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]